# How to show listening ports and TCP connections to the ports

Tags: netstat

Does anyone know what exact `netstat` commands in Ubuntu Server to use to show:

- Ports listening on on the server
- Current TCP connections to those ports

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try

```
netstat --tcp --listen --numeric-ports
```

Ex.

```
$ netstat --tcp --listen --numeric-ports
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    LISTEN
```

and

```
netstat --tcp --numeric-ports
```

Ex.

```
$ netstat --tcp --numeric-ports
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0    272 192.168.1.11:22         192.168.1.3:43444       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.11:22         192.168.1.2:65370       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.11:22         192.168.1.2:65369       ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good. I just wanted to know why one has to input numeric-ports at the end?

Comment: @fantamoja one has to use `--numeric-ports` (or the shortform option `-n`, equivalent to `--numeric-hosts --numeric-ports`) if one wants the port information numerically: by default, netstat will try to resolve ports to service names (so `:22` would become `:ssh` for example).  Choose whichever is more appropriate for your needs.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks for the info, appreciated!

Comment: what does `:::*` mean? would an external machine be able to connect to this port?

Comment: Could also be short to netstat -nplt, does the same thing.